# Where to get the older version silverlight 3?

Tags: silverlight

I installed silverlight 4 recently, but we still have legacy projects need to be tested on silverlight 3. Where can I get it?

Thanks!

Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use google or [that](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=D09B6ECF-9A45-4D99-B752-2A330A937BC4&displaylang=en) link.

Answer (score 1):

The Silverlight 4 plugin will behave like the Silverlight 3 plugin when the XAP version indicates its built with Silverlight 3.  This **includes** any bugs that Silverlight 3 had where the fixes for these bugs would break an existing Silverlight 3 app.  This is known as "quirksmode" (sounds familiar).

Whilst it is probably best for belts and braces to test Silverlight 3 apps on the actual Silverlight 3 plugin you will probably find that the same problems will be picked up even if you are using the Silverlight 4 plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this it? http://www.silverlight.net/getstarted/silverlight3/